# turning hashtags to link but ignoring the urls fragment Identifiers

Tags: php, regex, parsing, hashtag

I am doing a `preg_replace` to turn hashtags to urls using the following RegEx:

```
#([^0-9_\s\W][\p{L}0-9]{2,})
```

The problem is that url fragment identifiers are also getting included. How can I exclude them by improving this RegEx? Also every line may or many not be within `<p>` tags.

I appreciate your response.

Comment: please provide an example string and the expected response

Comment: The hash character will be in the match of the whole regexp, but the capture group will contain the tag without the hash character. So use `$1` to get what you want.

Comment: @Class `preg_replace` looks pretty much like PHP to me ;)

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/b1p and yes it is php. Sorry for not mentioning the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one made the work:

```
(?<=\W)#(\w+)
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/b1u

Comment: This one however fails if the hashtag is at the very beggining of the line, to address that you should use (?<=^|\W)#(\w+)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to exclude text like this from the matches:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996848#question-header
                                           \______________/
```

A simple solution would be to require a whitespace character before the `#`, which is easily done with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\s|^)#([^\d_\s\W][\p{L}\d]{2,})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rL2eT7/1).

Comment: Thank you Lucas for editing and the suggestion. The RegEx that you have suggested doesn't parse a hashtag at a beginning of a line.